# Python: Multiple Consensus sequences

Tags: python, bioinformatics, rosalind

starting from a list of dna sequences, I must have in return all the possible consensus (the resulting 
sequence with the highest nucleotide frequency in each position) sequences. If in some positions the  nucleotides have
the same highest frequency, I must obtain all possible combinations with the highest frequency.
I also must have in return the profile matrix ( a matrix with the frequencies of each nucleotide for each sequence).

This is my code so far (but it returns only one consensus sequence):

```
seqList = ['TTCAAGCT','TGGCAACT','TTGGATCT','TAGCAACC','TTGGAACT','ATGCCATT','ATGGCACT']
n = len(seqList[0])
profile = { 'T':[0]*n,'G':[0]*n ,'C':[0]*n,'A':[0]*n }

for seq in seqList:

    for i, char in enumerate(seq):
        profile[char][i] += 1



consensus = ""
for i in range(n):
    max_count = 0
    max_nt = 'x'
    for nt in "ACGT":
        if profile[nt][i] > max_count:
            max_count = profile[nt][i]
            max_nt = nt
    consensus += max_nt
print(consensus)
for key, value in profile.items():
     print(key,':', " ".join([str(x) for x in value] ))

TTGCAACT
C : 0 0 1 3 2 0 6 1
A : 2 1 0 1 5 5 0 0
G : 0 1 6 3 0 1 0 0
T : 5 5 0 0 0 1 1 6
```

(As you can see, in position four, C and G have the same highest score, it means  I must obtain two consensus sequences)

Is it possible to modify this code to obtain
all the possible sequences, or could you explain me the logic (the pseudocode) how to obtain the right result?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Currently your code print just the last seq, not the consensus one

Comment: Thank you, Ohad, sorry for the mistake, I fixed my code, now should return the consensus one. (but only one, so the primary problem remains :) . About your answer, the output must show the entire two sequences.

Comment: fixed that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways but this is a simple one:

```
bestseqs = [[]]
for i in range(n):
    d = {N:profile[N][i] for N in ['T','G','C','A']}
    m = max(d.values())
    l = [N for N in ['T','G','C','A'] if d[N] == m]
    bestseqs = [ s+[N] for N in l for s in bestseqs ]

for s in bestseqs:
    print(''.join(s))

# output:
ATGGAACT
ATGCAACT
```

Comment: @3lli0t You are welcome. You should accept the answer.